# jQuery: Display a static text from dynamic modal

Tags: jquery, ninja-forms

I'm using jQuery with WP Ninja Forms plugin and UIKit modal component to create and display dynamic alert from the Ninja Forms questionnaire.

I've search how to interact with Ninja Forms along with the jQuery and UIKit javascript function. Here's the code:

```
var labelBtn = [
  // Set 1
  "#nf-label-class-field-36-0",
  "#nf-label-class-field-81-1",
  "#nf-label-class-field-70-1",
  "#nf-label-class-field-96-1",
  "#nf-label-class-field-91-1",

  // Set 2
  "#nf-label-class-field-101-0",
];

for ( var id in labelBtn ) {

  var btn = labelBtn[id];
  (function(nf) {
    $(document).on( 'nfFormReady', function( e, layoutView ) {

      $(document).on('click', nf, function( e, layoutView) {

        var alertText = $('.alertText').find("aside").text();

        console.log(alertText);

        if ( $('.alertText').length > 0 ) {
                          $(".alertModal figcaption h2").text( alertText );
        }

        UIkit.modal('#AlertConsulation', { bgClose: false }).show();
      });

    }); // End of nfFormReady
  }(btn));

} // End Label Button
```

Basically, I have 10 different Symptoms category and each of the symptom category have multiple questionnaires and each of the questionnaire have alert text to be display when trigger a button. Alert text are static inside the Ninja Forms inside the `aside` tag and being pull-out and display to `.alertModal figcaption h2`.

This is when the browser load the Set 2, and clicked button Yes. No alert text display.
[image: 1st Click on Button Result]

This is when you click button No, and go back to button Yes, Alert text displayed.
[image: 2nd Click on Button Result]

The problem here is When I get to "Set 2" and click a button, Alert modal should be open and static text should be also in-place after the button triggered.

Note:
In my observation, it looks like the `nfFormReady` didn't load right away after the browser done loading. Or it might be something else?

Answer (score 0):

The case was because of my Ninja Forms conditional logic.

I hide the Alert Text (html code tag) when the form loads and wrap it to another conditional set when the button was clicked which was the cause of not displaying my text through my Modal component.

For reference:

Conditional Logic and hide everything except intro questionnaire including the alert text. 
Fix: Alert Text shouldn't be included here
[image: conditional logic 1]

Set the button Yes when clicked and display the Alert Text 
Fix: I shouldn't have this condition and let the CSS hide the Alert Text.
[image]